# Array data lost when returned from function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm sure this is a novice question but the book I'm studying from shows how to encode structurs into a buffer. However the examples are for simple types only.  I'm trying to take this one step further by using a dynamic array.

My problem is that after calling encode(), the calling function can see the value of bodyLen but the value of "body" is lost.  What am I doing wrong?

The pseudo code:

```
struct outData
{
    uint32_t bodyLen;       // Length of body
    uint32_t *body;         // Array of body elements
};

int encode(uint8_t *buffer, int size)
{
    // Set the buffer to the data structure layout
    outData *myData = (outData *)buffer;

    // Junk data (a nice 10101010...)
    uint32_t junk = 2863311530;

    // Populate body
    uint32_t bodyData[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        bodyData[i] = htonl(junk);
    }

    // Set the buffer
    myData->bodyLen = size;      // This works perfectly
    myData->body = bodyData;     // This is blank to calling function

    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This just returns a pointer to a function local buffer. It may be an usual approach to doing so but this topic has been discussed a lot of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bodyData` is a local variable, but you are setting `myData->body` to point to it. After `encode` returns, `bodyData` is destroyed and `*myData->body` is now undefined.

To fix, you need to do a deep copy of the contents of `bodyData` into `myData->body` after properly allocating the space (with `new[]`). And then you need to be sure to `delete[]` it later.

Comment: Why should they bother with `new` and `delete` (or actually `new[]` and `delete[]`)? Just use a `std::vector`, and it can replace the entire `struct OutData`.

Comment: @Angew I agree that would (probably) be better; just addressing the code as written since OP stated it was a learning exercise. The point about the array forms is a good one.

Comment: This really helped. Seems so obvious now. Thank you!